# service to access and update the variable in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-components

I have variable authentication which i set the false like this in app root component

```
 import { Component ,Input} from '@angular/core' ;


 @Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl:'./app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

})
export class AppComponent {
  authenticated = false;


}
```

I have used the component routing in angular 2 using layout
my html code for this is

```
        <app-nav-menu *ngIf="!authenticated"></app-nav-menu>

</div>

<div [ngClass]="{'campaign-process':authenticated}" >

    <app-side-menu *ngIf="authenticated"></app-side-menu>
<div [ngClass]="{'campaign-content':authenticated}">

    <app-upr-div-seach *ngIf="authenticated"></app-upr-div-seach>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>


</div><!--campaign content-->
```

i want to update this authentication variable in child component (login component) some can please make a service for sharing and accessing this in child component 
  how can i do this 
thanks in advance

Edited
ths is component file

```
  import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent  {





  clickedLogin(event)
  {
  console.log('here i want to update this ');

  }

 }
```

Comment: did you check the answr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a service to update the variable as follows,

```
@Injectable()
export class sharedService {
 authenticated :boolean;
 constructor() {
}
 Initialize() {
    this.authenticated = false;
}

 Update(input:any) {
    this.authenticated = input;
 }
}
```

Make sure to inject to your module, later you can call the method Update and Initalize to do whatever you need.

Then in Component1.ts

```
import { sharedService } from '/services/sharedService.service';
 constructor( private sharedSer : sharedService ) {

    }

Update(){
  this.sharedSer.Update(yourvalu);
}
```

Comment: How can i add this in my component ts file . can u please guide me im new in angular2 @Sajeetharan

Comment: i dnt have it here update question where i want to update this variable

Comment: when i write constructr line `constructor( private sharedSer : sharedService ) {

    }`  it give me error on browser conosole and component does not show up

Comment: error is ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for SharedServiceService!
Error

Comment: ok you need to add the SharedServiceService to the imports inside the module

Comment: how can i do this ? in app.module ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141612/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-asad).